# Android Minimum Button Height: 48dp = 9mm?

Tags: android, mobile

I'm currently working on wireframes for a mobile app and there's something that seems to slip my mind: In the [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html), they state the following:

> On average, 48dp translate to a physical size of about 9mm (with some
>   variability).

But, according to the [Android Developpers Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), they calculate a `dp` using the following formula:

> The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a
>   160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system
>   for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently
>   handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual
>   density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen
>   pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi
>   screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp
>   units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of
>   your UI on screens with different densities.

So let say that for simplicity, I'm doing my design at 160dpi so my graphics have the right size according to recommended standards. When printed, I scale down my document by 2,22 (160dpi/72dpi) so the printed result gives the actual physical size on paper.

I want my buttons to be 48dp high. But if I do the maths, following everything I read, I'm nowhere close to a 9mm size by specifying 48 as my button height.

> 48dp / 160dpi = 0.3 inches, so 7.62 mm...

What am I clearly missing/doing wrong? Where is that 9mm coming from?

Thanks!

**Update**

Here's what helped me understand what I was missing from the accepted answer.

Take as an example the screen density of 200. Android will use 240 to base its calculations. So:

- 240dpi / 160dpi = 1,5 of scale
- 48dp * 1,5 of scale = 78 physical pixels
- 78 px / 240dpi = 0,3 inches (which is exactly the same as 48dp / 160dpi)

Now the trick is that the actual device density was 200. So the pixels will appear bigger than on a 240dpi screen. To get the physical size on the 200dpi device, we have to get the difference between both resolution and apply it to the 0,3 inches:

- 240dpi / 200dpi = 1,2
- 0,3 in * 1,2 of difference = 0,36in which gives 9,144mm

I know this is exactly the same as stated by @kabuko:

> (48dp / 200ppi) * 1.5 * 25.4 mm/in = 9.14400

but the step by step way helped me figuring out what was happening under the hood.

Comment: Interesting, they do point out that there's some variability to be accounted for, but how much are they speaking of when they say "some variability". You've got me puzzled...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The exact statement you're referencing is:

> On average, 48dp translate to a physical size of about 9mm

If you look at this image from the [Supporting Multiple Screens doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

[image: Android Densities]

You'll see that there are density buckets (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi). Each of these are not fixed densities, but rather a range of densities which end up mapping to fixed numbers used for various density calculations (120, 160, 240, 320 respectively). 160 is rarely the actual pixels per inch for an mdpi device, it's just the abstracted value used for simplicity's sake.

Your calculations are correct, but you assume that 160ppi is the average density (assuming mdpi devices) just because 160dpi is the abstracted value for mdpi. Apparently it's not, if the statement you reference is indeed true. I suspect that there are a lot of devices which average out to around 200ppi which end up getting categorized as hdpi. That would be: (48dp / 200ppi) * 1.5 * 25.4 mm/in = 9.14400 mm. Just a guess, but certainly I think the underlying reason is that the average isn't 160ppi.

**Update:**

Here's another quote from the doc from the design site:

> If you design your elements to be at least 48dp high and wide you can guarantee that [...] your targets will never be smaller than the minimum recommended target size of 7mm regardless of what screen they are displayed on.

So the size varies from > 7mm to at least 9mm (given 9mm is supposed to be average I would think the top range should be < 11mm). Yes, 48dp should be "approximately" the same size on all screens, but what "approximately" really means is not really specified. Your 7.62mm is within range. Their 9mm value is just for the "average" which is an unspecified ppi.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as hard as I am trying to understand it, something is bugging me:

Comment: Sorry, new with the editor...

In the documentation of the same page you referred, they state that a "dp" is 1 physical pixel on a 160dpi screen.

So if a "dp" is in fact on a base of 160dpi, there's is no assumption about the pixel density used for calculations. 48dp, whatever the screen resolution is, should always translate in the approximately same physical size, the OS scaling the end result according to the px = dp * (dpi/160) formula.

In your example, you take 48/200 * 1.5, but it would actually be, on my understanding, 1.25. Back to square one... :(

But again, I know I must be wrong!

Comment: I've updated the description to give more precision that might give clues on why I'm confused. Thanks again for your help by the way!

Comment: I think I'm missing something with the 1.25 thing, but otherwise my postulation is that your calculations are accurate it's just that there's subtly to the statement you quoted that isn't immediately obvious. I'll update my post with a few more details.

Comment: 1.25 is the scale coming from 200dpi/160dpi. Or am I not understanding what's your 1.5?

Comment: Ahh, ok. That's the misunderstanding. The thing is, there's abstracted density (ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xdpi : 120dpi/160dpi/240dpi/320dpi) which is what Android uses to do these calculations and then there's actual physical density (pixels per inch). If you take a 200ppi device it might get bucketed into hdpi, which is 240dpi. So even if the device is really 200ppi, Android will use 240dpi for all of its calculations.

Comment: Ho, I completely missed the point of your answer, even after reading the documentation 3 times and your answer a couple of times too! So my 1.25 is wrong... because a screen of 200dpi would actually be returned by the OS as a 240dpi screen (the hdpi bucket), resulting to a 1.5 scale. Now I understand that 48dp will always give 0,3 inches after scaling, but because of the generalized densities (buckets), this 0.3 inches might be physically scaled up or down due to the difference between the actual device density and the generalized one.

Comment: Pretty close. 48dp will give approximately 0.3 in, but because Android actually never uses actual density but instead only the generalized density, you don't really know exactly what physical size it is on an actual device, only that it's reasonably close.

Answer (score 1):

If speaking **strictly about Android Phone and Tablets** (no TV, no Wear, no Desktops, no iOS):
According to google's list of devices https://design.google.com/devices/ the 48dp to 9mm recommendation *does not really match real world values it seems*.

I needed to find the lowest DP value to use that will safely render at or above a given physical size everywhere. Turns out some devices are just *badly* configured (Sony Experia C4 being the worst in this list at 200 dp/in, next is the Dell Venue 8 at 180dp/in, then LG G3 at 178dp/in)  (here talking logical DP not physical DPI). In those devices, everything will look smaller than average. Everything else is close to 170..144 dp/in.

If this info can be found elsewhere to concur the data and also have more devices it would be nice in case we see there are more rogue devices out there.

Here's some numbers I extracted from the page: (only android phone and tablets)

```
Max: 200 dp/in  (smallest)
Min: 141 dp/in  (biggest)
```

With these numbers, here's a table for the min/max mm size for various discrete dp values to choose from (rounded to nearest 1/10 mm):

```
dp  min  max mm
36  4.6   6.5
37  4.7   6.7
38  4.8   6.8
39  5.0   7.0
40  5.1   7.2
41  5.2   7.4
42  5.3   7.6
43  5.5   7.7
44  5.6   7.9
45  5.7   8.1
46  5.8   8.3
47  6.0   8.5
48  6.1   8.6
49  6.2   8.8
50  6.4   9.0
51  6.5   9.2
52  6.6   9.4
53  6.7   9.5
54  6.9   9.7
55  7.0   9.9
56  7.1  10.1
57  7.2  10.3
58  7.4  10.4
59  7.5  10.6
```

### Formula

`mm = <dp> * 25.4 / <dp/in>` 
where `<dp/in>` is either the max dense dp/in (200) or low dense (141) I could find on this device list.

### Example

`48dp * 25.4 / 200 = 6.096mm`

rounded: 6.1 mm -- which is below the "safe" 7mm their are claiming.

Also note that 48dp never quite reaches "9mm" on any phone/tablet screens. Max being 8.6 (which is close but certainly not an average).